# What does bondo outgas?

Tags: body-work

Does anybody know the gas that Bondo outgasses when drying? A neighbour is sensitive to certain gasses and he needs to know if he will be affected by Bondo. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Material Safety Data Sheet](http://www.dosha.org/msds/Bondo%20Body%20Filler.pdf) the hazardous ingredient is listed as Styrene. I would recommend you wear a respirator and some good gloves.

Some import points from the [MSDS](http://www.dosha.org/msds/Bondo%20Body%20Filler.pdf):

> Signs of Overexposure: Nausea, cough, dizziness, weakness, headache, chest pain, lack of coordination, shortness
>   of breath, dermatitis, redness and/or pain in eyes.
>
> Emergency First Aid: Move to fresh air, remove contaminated clothing, wash effected skin with soap and water, do not
>   use solvents or thinners; if product gets into eyes, remove contact lenses, flush with water for 15 minutes.
>
> Handling: If handling in a confined space wear an organic vapor cartridge respirator (NIOSH / OSHA). For working,
>   wear solvent resistant gloves and safety eye protection designed to guard against liquid splashes. Close all containers
>   tightly after use. Do not eat, drink or smoke in work areas.
>
> Other Precautions: Vapors are heavier than air and may travel along floors. Material has an offensive odor.
>   Prolonged exposure may reduce the user’s sensitivity to the odor, thus reducing the effectiveness of odor as a warning
>   against exposure.

UPDATE: 3M has a site where you can search for 3M's MSDS of the specific Bondo product you are using.  It looks like some of the hazardous ingredients may be different depending upon the specific product. [3M MSDS Search](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/MSDS/Search/?gsaAction=msdsSRA&type=ptn&msdsLocale=en_US)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know. I did not know the term MSDS to google, but now I do.

Comment: @dotancohen Material Safety Data Sheet, and you're most welcome

Answer (score 1):

One brand of body filler I used claimed to emit a neurotoxin.  Read the can carefully for safety information.

Comment: I've had the same experience.  Now I want to find it and look up the toxin.