# What is OSHA/NIOSH?

Tags: terminology

I have heard both OSHA and NIOSH mentioned in [answers here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/what-does-bondo-outgas) what are they and why do I need to be concerned about them when it comes to working on my car?

*This is inspired by [a question from Wyatt Barmore](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90828/automotive-education) on proposed similar site in the SE family.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSHA is the [Occupational Safety & Health Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_Safety_and_Health_Administration). This is a United States government agency which belongs to the [US Department of of Labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Labor). According to the Wiki article:

> OSHA's mission is to "assure safe and healthful working conditions for working men and women by setting and enforcing standards and by providing training, outreach, education and assistance". The agency is also charged with enforcing a variety of whistleblower statutes and regulations.

NIOSH is the [National Institute for Occupational Safety and Health](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_for_Occupational_Safety_and_Health). According to the Wiki article:

> The National Institute for Occupational Safety and Health (NIOSH) is the U.S. federal agency responsible for conducting research and making recommendations for the prevention of work-related injury and illness. NIOSH is part of the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) within the U.S. Department of Health and Human Services.

OSHA's main goal is to ensure a healthy work environment and can enforce laws. NIOSH's main goal is to help prevent work place injury by exploring better ways to do work.

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard both OSHA and NIOSH mentioned in answers here what are they and why do I need to be concerned about them when it comes to working on my car?

Honestly, you don't have to be concerned with OSHA regulations unless you are working in a workplace, professionally, that abides by OSHA regulations (which is every legal US business, iirc).

Although, a lot of their safety regulations are good information to know.